# Event log warning Registry setting specifying configuration file does not exist

Tags: sql, ms-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

```
Microsoft SSIS Service: 
Registry setting specifying configuration file does not exist. 
Attempting to load default config file.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

this is my MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DtsServiceConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StopExecutingPackagesOnShutdown>true</StopExecutingPackagesOnShutdown>
  <TopLevelFolders>
    <Folder xsi:type="SqlServerFolder">
      <Name>MSDB</Name>
      <ServerName>.\SQL2008</ServerName>
    </Folder>
    <Folder xsi:type="FileSystemFolder">
      <Name>File System</Name>
      <StorePath>..\Packages</StorePath>
    </Folder>
  </TopLevelFolders>
</DtsServiceConfiguration>
```

I found [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789.aspx) that I need to update my registry. But the only entry at 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SSIS\ServiceConfigFile`
is `(Default)` with no value.

What must I add in registry so that I do not get this error any more?

Comment: If this happened after you installed SQL Server 2008 SP1, it looks like that it is by design. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/696610/sql-server-2008-r2-installing-service-pack-1-removes-registry-data-causing-event-id-274

Answer (score 4):

In your registry, go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTS\ServiceConfigFile
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\ServiceConfigFile
```

if value is empty then add in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2014 registry key location is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SSIS\ServiceConfigFile
```

`(Default)` registry value should be

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml
```

Comment: @DavidPostill my point was that registry location is different in SQL Server 2014

Comment: Fair enough. :)